# Ancient Notable Schoars those who studied music - were they sinners according to Islam?

Tags: history, islamic-scholar, music

Adaab.

Recently many people in social media, including some of my Muslim friends, are literally scared that music has covered up the globe, and they thinks it is very sinful.

I have seen many past Quora and Stackexchange questions which asked whether music is sinful, and there are admixtures of answers. Some say it is strictly prohibited and sinful, some other sects consider it to be permissible up to limits. But my question is something else.

**From immemorable past, many notable Muslim scholars (not necessarily Islamic preacher but scholars who were Muslim) did lot of contribution to music and music theory. This includes Al Farabi, Al Kindi, Al Ghazali, Banu Musa, and many others.**

**My question is, are these scholars considered to be sinner according to Islam?**  Because they were knowledgeable person in islam, still they contributed in music? This looks very contradictory. Were they not considered as sinners? Were they forgiven or considered as some sort of exception?

Kindly pardon weak English.

Comment: Aren't the mentioned people in *"notable Muslim scholars"* just Muslim philosophers,  polymath , physicians etc. Would be better to provide their contribution to Islam and Music or any other impermissible stuff.

Comment: @AbduRahman Make it an answer?

Comment: You can edit your question, to provide that. It is located beneath your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked: According to Islam.

This raises the question who defines Islam.

It is finally God Who decides. The scholars have the task to find out and teach according to their understanding of the Quran and Hadith.

Just on the subject of music, the picture from hadith is all but clear; that is why the answers differ considerably between scholars.

In Sunni Islam, Imams are not considered infaillible. It is allowed to an educated scholar to come to a different conclusion but this does not mean that the option to be in error can be excluded.

Therefore, there's no unique answer from "Islam". There is evidence from the Quran or from universally recognised hadith all significant scholars agree to, so that we can say that it is a universal teaching in Islam.

In the matters of music, sources and opinions are too divergent as that one could say that there's an answer "according to Islam", and it seems that music was not considered forbidden by the aforementioned scholars.

Comment: what does it mean by "All but clear"? can you simplify that English?

Comment: Regardless of the difference amongst scholars, one should keep in mind that music that defy Islam, Sharia or Islamic figures is Haram.

Comment: @AbduRahman is there really any such music that humiliates or opposes them? I can't remember any. But there are many songs supporting Islam.

Comment: Of course music can be haram in words or purpose.

Comment: @Oud As jeschu stated, a few examples of this would be how modern songs promotes drugs, Zina, satanism or any other evil through lyrics.

Comment: @AbduRahman Thanks for making it clear. I missed it because I don't listen most kind of modern songs. However I listen  instrumental music which doesnt have any vocals or lyrics.

Comment: @AbduRahman To be honest, instrumental music makes me think of almighty, makes me remember of almighty, it reminds me the vastness of ocean and broadness of the space. How this can be a controversial subject is beyond my little intelligence.